# Why the inject Service Instance's attribute is null in Controller? initialize Timeline with “new” Operator, @Autowired,@PostConstruct?

Tags: java, spring-boot

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class ApiService {
    public Map<String, String> map_khmcKhbh2;

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    @PostConstruct
    private void postConstruct() {
        map_khmcKhbh2 = new HashMap<String, String>(){
            {
                put("aaa","111");
                put("bbb","222");
            }
        };
        log.warn("PostConstruct"); //yes print when starting
    }
    public Map<String, String> map_khmcKhbh2() {
        return this.map_khmcKhbh2;
    }
}
```

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("")
@Slf4j
public class ApiController{
    @Autowired
    ApiService service;

    @RequestMapping("/external/dropKhmcKhbh2")
    public Object dropKhmcKhbh22() {
        log.debug(service.toString());
        return service.map_khmcKhbh2();  //that's ok
//      return service.map_khmcKhbh2; //that's null
    }
}
```

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.9.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
```

when call
http://ip:6994/dtjy/external/dropKhmcKhbh2
use "service.map_khmcKhbh2()" can get the data,
"service.map_khmcKhbh2" cannot,response 200 but null

how the object initialize  timeline with “new” Operator, @Autowired,@PostConstruct

I think i don't know something，please help me thank you!

---

Update:

I found something:
when i Exclude other dependent packages and classes
both service.map_khmcKhbh2 and service.map_khmcKhbh2() are ok!

when service.map_khmcKhbh2 not working i found that info:

> "m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor : No match for [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/webp, application/xml;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8], supported: []"

when service.map_khmcKhbh2() is ok ,the info is:

> m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor : Using 'application/json;q=0.8', given [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/webp, application/xml;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8] and supported [application/json, application/*+json]

so problem is that RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor not select the
response content-type(beause "supported: []),and the browser treat it as "plain text document",beause i found the browser  warning:

> "The character encoding of the plain text document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the file needs to be declared in the transfer protocol or file needs to use a byte order mark as an encoding signature"

but i have not found the reason why In the same environment

> RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor  say "support []" content-type
> when i using service.map_khmcKhbh2

---

why RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor say "support []",reason probably that service.map_khmcKhbh2 return null ,why null? i found the
@Autowired service in  ApiController ,its Class is "ApiService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$36288273  (id=221)" and its attribute "map_khmcKhbh2" is value null
but in my simplest test project the service Class is "ApiService  (id=143)" and its attribute "map_khmcKhbh2"  has Map value

what or how cause CGLIB porxy and why ApiService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$36288273 has null attribute,i donot  know yet~

some info useful,that display once on console:

> WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
> WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils (file:/home/ypf/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/5.2.13.RELEASE/spring-core-5.2.13.RELEASE.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
> WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils
> WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
> WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release

Comment: Normally, this should work and the ApiService would be injected. It's hard to analyze from these two code snippets. Please try to edit your question and create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: does `ApiService` package  included in the component scanning?

Comment: @deadshot otherwise he won't be able autowire it inside `ApiController`

Comment: I gave this a try, it actually worked fine!